# QGIS3.14 Resource Sharing symbols are not appearing in atlas export via standalone python script

Tags: python, plugins, gis, qgis, atlas

I created a standalone python script to export my atlas layouts. Everything is working great except that the SVG symbols that I am using from the Resource Sharing plugin are just question marks, assuming that it is having trouble locating them. However, if I run the script via the startup.py in the QGIS3 folder everything works like expected. I would really like to avoid using this method though as it prevents you from using QGIS until the script finishes, which takes about 2 hours. I am hoping that I just need to add a simple environmental variable to my .bat file so that it can locate the Resource Sharing plugin. Thanks in advance for any help!

**.bat file**

```
@ECHO off

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.3\bin\pycharm64.exe"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

**Python Script**

```
from qgis.core import  QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsLayoutExporter
import os
import sys

def export_atlas(qgs_project_path, layout_name, outputs_folder):

    # Open existing project
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.read(qgs_project_path)

    print(f'Project in "{project.fileName()} loaded successfully')

    # Open prepared layout that as atlas enabled and set
    layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name)

    # Export atlas
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
    exporter.exportToPdfs(layout.atlas(), outputs_folder, settings)


def run():
    # Start a QGIS application without GUI
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis", True)
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    qgs.initQgis()
    sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

    project_path = [project_path]
    output_folder = [export_location]
    layout_name_portrait = [portrait layout name]
    layout_name_landscape = [landscape laytout name]

    export_atlas(project_path, layout_name_portrait, output_folder)
    export_atlas(project_path, layout_name_landscape, output_folder)

    # Close the QGIS application
    qgs.exitQgis()

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it might have something to do with the setting `svg/searchPathsForSVG`.

```
QgsSettings().setValue('svg/searchPathsForSVG', <your path>)
```